# How can I insert many field values under one term?

Tags: 8, database

I'm working on a module, of which one function is grab list names and stock codes from a custom table and create corresponding terms. Now, my current code creates a new term and corresponding stock code, however this is not very efficient. How can I create one term for each unique list name and create corresponding many field values? Below is my current code:

```
function liste() {
    $src = ['Ý', 'Þ', 'ý', 'þ', 'ð'];
    $tar = ['İ', 'Ş', 'ı', 'ş', 'ğ'];
    $query = \Drupal::database()->select("excel","m")->fields("m",["stokkodu","grupadi"])->condition("grupadi", "","!=")->execute()->fetchAll();
    foreach ($query as $q) {
        $term = Term::create([
            'vid' => 'liste_adi',
            'name' => str_replace($src, $tar, $q->grupadi),
            'field_stok_kodu' => $q->stokkodu,
        ]);
        $term->enforceIsNew();
        $term->save();
    }
}
```

I thought about selecting only grupadi and grouping by it and inserting to a temporary table and then inserting corresponding stock codes in another column delimited with comma or something; but if there is another more efficient way, please let me know. EDIT: I'm looking to do something like the following:

Current:

```
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2299001      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2299002      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2299003      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2299004      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2299005      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2303001      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2303002      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2303003      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2303004      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2303017      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2303022      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2303046      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2601044      |
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2608020      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Desired:

```
| Manyetik Matkaplar?n Yedek Par�alar?                                                | YMD2299001,YMD2299002,YMD2299003
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the below. It might be overkill but does the job.

```
function liste() {
    $src = ['Ý', 'Þ', 'ý', 'þ', 'ð'];
    $tar = ['İ', 'Ş', 'ı', 'ş', 'ğ'];
    $grupadi = \Drupal::database()->select("excel","e")->fields("e",["grupadi"])->condition("grupadi", "","!=")->groupBy("grupadi")->execute()->fetchAll();
    foreach ($grupadi as $g) {
        $term = Term::create([
            'vid' => 'liste_adi',
            'name' => str_replace($src, $tar, $g->grupadi),
        ]);
        $term->enforceIsNew();
        $term->save();
    }
    $terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("taxonomy_term")->loadTree("liste_adi");
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $stokkodu = \Drupal::database()->select("excel", "e")->fields("e", ["stokkodu"])->condition("grupadi", $term->name)->execute()->fetchAll();
        foreach($stokkodu as $s) {
            $t = Term::load($term->tid);
            $t->field_stok_kodu[] = $s->stokkodu;
            $t->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You needn't have to do aggregation via temporary tables, it can be done in your query via a `GROUP_CONCAT` expression & `GROUP` clause:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select("excel","m")->fields("m",["stokkodu","grupadi"])->condition("grupadi", "","!=");
$query->addExpression('GROUP_CONCAT(m.stokkodu)', 'stokkodus');
$query->groupBy('m.grupadi');
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll(); 
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $result->stokkodus contains a comma-delimited list of values that you can split with explode()
  $stokkodus = explode(',');
  // @TODO: add transform logic
}
```

In the example above, you can transform the exploded array then create an array of values for your multivalue `field_stok_kodu` field:

```
  // @TODO: add transform logic
  'field_stok_kodu' => [
    ['value' => $stokkodus[0]],
    ['value' => $stokkodus[1]]
  ];
```